# Partition files by size on PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark to partition a df and write 10 partitions on S3:

```
df.repartition(10).write.format("json").mode("OverWrite").save("s3Bucket")
```

How can I partition the df but basing on the partitions size and not the number of partitions. Ex: I want to have n partitions of 50 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DataFrame is loaded from files located in your bucket, you can get the size of the input files and use it to calculate the number of partitions.

Something like this should work:

```
data_path = "/s3Bucket/path/"
PARTITION_BLOCK_SIZE = 50000000 # 50MB

# using Hadoop FS API to get data len
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

fs = Path(data_path).getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
data_size = fs.getFileStatus(Path(data_path)).getLen()

# repartition if size > 50MB
if (data_size / PARTITION_BLOCK_SIZE) > 1:
    nb_partitions = math.ceil(data_size / PARTITION_BLOCK_SIZE)
    df = df.repartition(nb_partitions)
```